# How can I pass an id of "0" into my application URL? (CodeIgniter)

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter for my projects and I would like to pass an id of 0 into the URL:

> /resource/method/id

which translates into

> /resource/method/0

the problem is that CodeIgniter ignores the 0 and responds to

> /resource/method

Any workaround for this?

Comment: `/resource/method/0` Works well for me. Tested with CI2.1.4

Comment: Thanks for your comment. After reading it i saw that the problem is even more particular. /resource/method/0 works fine too but i realize that it just doesn't work when we are trying to pass data for the index method: /client/index/0

Comment: Seems weird because I tested `home/index/0` and it worked.

Comment: Could you tell me wich values do you have in your config.php for the following variable?  $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';

Comment: Sure, I've changed it a little to fit my needs: `'a-z \(\)\{\}\[\]0-9~%.:_\-'`

Comment: thanks, unfortunately it still doesn't work. Are you defining a default value for the resource $id in your controller (as @Zarathuztra mentioned?)

Comment: Well, yes. I've no idea why it doesn't work for you...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47135/discussion-between-lothre1-and-hashem-qolami)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why codeigniter, rather PHP is ignoring the id of 0 is because of PHP's type juggling.

0, "" (empty string) and false are all the same to PHP

When getting the URL segment, if  codeigniter doesn't see the parameters it returns false.
Although this is probably why you aren't getting the value. I've never seen the framework ignore the id.

Remember that:
    `(false == 0)` is true
while `(false === 0)` is false

The first example checks if both values are equal, while the second checks if both are equal and the same type

Answer (score 0):

if this is giving you trouble, in your resource controller, do the following:

```
public function method($id = 0){
//stuff
}
```

This way, it won't matter if you pass in the id as 0 or not, no id will mean the same thing, unless this is not your intended behavior. If you need to modify this in any way, just setup a route.

Comment: But I've a small problem. Id of 0 is a valid resource id. When nothing is provided i want to fetch a collection. Not the resource where the id is 0:/

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. If codeigniter is lopping off the 0 (which I don't know why it would, never seen that behavior) just create a route to help. For example, you could even make your URL's a little more restful by doing something like: /resource/0/method as a route

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to solve the situation after all (well I think so).

consider `0` an exception and pass it to the url as `zero` and make some appropriate conditions in your controller to check the value passed and run codes accordingly!

```
/resource/method/zero
```